# What do I need to have inside of my sources.list file?

Tags: apt, sudo, raspberry-pi

I can't download a thing. When I run `sudo apt-get` for any program I get the error

> Package [insert name here] has no installation candidate.

I've looked online and there are hundreds of examples of what the `source.list` file should have in it.

Can someone tell me what I need? All I want is to be able to run these commands

`sudo apt-get install qt3-dev-tools`

`sudo apt-get install synaptic`

`sudo apt-get install bc`

Comment: `cat /etc/debian_version` to know if you have version 7 or 8 debian for a start. 7 means wheezy, 8 means jessie.

Comment: `cat /etc/os-release` if you have it will also give clues as to what you installed.

Answer (score 2):

Two lines should be enough for raspberrian ([doc](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository)), assuming you are using the version based on debian wheezy  (check with lsb_release -a):

```
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
```

"after changing sources.list don't forget to sudo apt-get update" (thanks drewbenn)

This is the master repository, there are others, which may be closer to you.

The package you want are in the main repository. If this doesn't work, then the problem doesn't lie with the sources list.